# Target genes for piRNA

Tags: rna-seq, gene, genome, non-coding

Where I can find a database or tool to give me the `target genes of PIWI (piRNAs)` in `human`?

I found one but works for worm like `piRTarBase`

There are a lot for miRNAs around but not for piRNAs

Answer (score 1):

### Update

It does indeed appear that while piRBase etc. have human piRNAs, they do not have target information.

Looking at [related questions](https://www.biostars.org/p/235278/), recommendations are made to map piRNA sequences to the genome to find the targets. One tool recommended is [PiPipes](https://github.com/bowhan/piPipes), which might assume read input but otherwise might give some ideas.

### Original answer

piRBase [has this](http://bigdata.ibp.ac.cn/piRBase/target.php). See "target mRNA" field.

Comment: Thank you. Can I use that for human? because all are for non human likely

Comment: @Exhausted You are right- how odd. THey have human piRNAs in the db but none of them seem to have targets. I missed that, sorry. I will see if I can figure it out and if